# Are all versions of App in Google App Engine always running/ready-to-run?

Tags: google-app-engine

I am able to run any version in the "Versions" section of App Engine.

Are all versions of App running or ready-to-run any time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Though any version that's not the default version is likely to require a bit of startup time for the instance.

Comment: Thank you @Samson.